# M2.2.5 Frontend SQL Error

Tags: error, magento-2.2.5

I am sorry if this has been asked before, but I am getting a strange error with mysql whenever I try to load any of the non cached indexed pages, the admin backend seems to work fine, and any non product page like 404 or our location page works, and reindexing always fails.

I'm running 2.2.5 CE
On Ubuntu 16.04.5
PHP 7.0.30
MySQL 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

```
Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1030 Got error 1 from storage engine
```

Comment: This error is something like out of disk space. Discuss with your hosting provider and check the disk space.